how to shift right with only + - & | and tests for >, < ==
Asked before but got closed due to lack of detail. So here is more info
I am working on cp without shift or rotate.
It supports

add & subtract
logical & and logical or
conditional jump on > < == or any combination of those (>=...)

I can see how to shift left using repeated add to self. I can do the rotate by testing the leftmost bit before shift and oring it onto the rightmost after shift.
I cant figure out a right shift mechanism though

To do a right shift we want to divide by 2 for each step and here's an example in C++ using only +, - and >=.
template<class T>
T rightshift(T value, int steps) {
    T div = 1;
    while(steps--)  div += div; // steps=1 => 2, 2 => 4 etc.
    
    // do the division:
    T res = 0;
    while(value >= div) { // subtract div from value until it's less than div
        value -= div;
        ++res;            // and count the number of times we subtract
    }
    // value will here contain the remainder of the division

    return res;
}


thanks for fixing the wrong include pm. I just realized a simpler way so I won't need numeric_limits now :)

thats neat - ty. I could only think of rotating left a long way as a way to shift right

@pm100 Odd. I upvoted it because I thought the question was clear.

how about rotate, i can probably work out an inefficient way

@pm100 The straight forward way would be to combine a left shift and a right shift. I'm not sure if it's possible to make it more efficient with the current constraints.
